# How to invoke an event within Parallel.ForEachAsync in C# without hanging UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel.foreachasync

I'm trying to invoke an event within a `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, and it's hanging my UI or erroring back to the program.cs

The event on my class is being consumed by the UI to increment a progress bar. It works great when done in a `foreach` but not in the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. I've tried to make my event async but that did not help any.

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync<Individual>(INDlist, async (individual, token) =>
    {
        if (Cancel) throw new OperationCanceledException("Interface cancelled by the user");
        await UpdateIndividualAsync(individual);
        await IncrementProgress?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    });
```

Comment: How many elements does the `INDlist` contains? How frequently is the `IncrementProgress` called?

Comment: It would vary but it would be between 1000 and 100,000. The progress increment is called for each one.

Comment: Could you try invoking the `IncrementProgress` event less frequently, for example just 10 times in total, and see if this solves the problem?

Comment: I'll give that a try and see. I'll try firing the event after every hundred it finishes.

Comment: That worked. I just increment the progress bar by 100 every time it finished 100 iterations. I guess seeing that the progress bar max is typically between 5000 and 100,000 incrementing it only 1 step at a time is a little overkill anyway. Thank you for the help

Comment: Reporting progress too frequently is a common mistake. If you want you could close your question as a duplicate of a similar question, like this one: [ProgressBar slowing my code by a factor of ~25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710413/progressbar-slowing-my-code-by-a-factor-of-25-async).

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to close this as a duplicate. I posted the answer but it won't let me accept my own answer until tomorrow.

Comment: There is a "Close" button under the tags, where you can paste the URL of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by firing the event less often. As the event was consumed by the UI it seemed to overwhelm it